# How to create such diagram in r studio? (boxplot, points over bar plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Please have a look at this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4NUl.jpg)

Hi,

first up: I'am pretty new to R and programming in general. I want to reproduce a analysis of data with my own code. I would like to represent my data with ggplot 2 in r studio in a similar way (please take a look at the picture). I have already extracted to mean values in a seperate data set.

What kind of visualisation could that be? I have tried looking at the [ggplot2 cheatsheet](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/STAT3022/r/current/Misc/data-visualization-2.1.pdf) but could not figure it out.

Thanks for your help :)

I'am trying to extract the mean data from the set like this:

```
ean_values_polVertrauen <- polVertrauen %>%
  summarize(
    BUNDESVERFASSUNGSGERICHT = mean(pt02),
    BILDUNG = mean(pt11),
    POLIZEI = mean(pt14),
    JUSTIZ = mean(pt08),
    GESUNDHEITSWESEN = mean(pt01),
    VERWALTUNG = mean(pt04),
    BUNDESTAG = mean(pt03),
    BUNDESREGIERUNG = mean(pt12),
    EUROPKOMMISSION = mean(pt19),
    EUROPPARLAMENT = mean(pt20),
    PARTEIEN = mean(pt15),
  )
```

my output for

```
mean_values_polVertrauen
```

is

```
variable    value
1  BUNDESVERFASSUNGSGERICHT 4.249473
2                   BILDUNG 4.200120
3                   POLIZEI 3.950045
4                    JUSTIZ 3.579898
5          GESUNDHEITSWESEN 3.941920
6                VERWALTUNG 3.486909
7                 BUNDESTAG 3.058381
8           BUNDESREGIERUNG 3.055673
9           EUROPKOMMISSION 2.512489
10           EUROPPARLAMENT 2.553416
11                 PARTEIEN 2.190190
```

Comment: I use and recommend https://r-graph-gallery.com as a great source for ideas, for both *"what kinds of plots do a good job depicting the data"* as well as *"how do I make it"*. The examples include pictures, sample data, and code to reproduce them, very informative. FYI, I don't know what (if any) substantive changes were made, but https://posit.co/resources/cheatsheets/?type=posit-cheatsheets&_page=2/ has a newer version of the ggplot2 cheatsheet, updated in 2021.

Comment: With a reproducible example it will be easier to be more specific in the any answers. See here for help on how to do this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please put a repdoducible example in your question next time (with `dput` for example).

Now to your plot. Following code reproduces the graphic. There are a few exceptions: The shape of the points is either custom or a combination of `geom_errorbar` and `geom_point`. Since you did not provide data for an error bar, the code below just produces points.
The theme of the plot is custom. You can either build your theme with for example [this (RPubs)](https://rpubs.com/mclaire19/ggplot2-custom-themes) page or select a existing theme from [here (r-charts)](https://r-charts.com/ggplot2/themes/).

```
df <- data.frame(variable = c("BUNDESVERFASSUNGSGERICHT",
                              "BILDUNG",
                              "POLIZEI",
                              "JUSTIZ",
                              "GESUNDHEITSWESEN",
                              "VERWALTUNG",
                              "BUNDESTAG",
                              "BUNDESREGIERUNG",
                              "EUROPKOMMISSION",
                              "EUROPPARLAMENT",
                              "PARTEIEN"),
                 value = c(4.249473,
                           4.200120,
                           3.950045,
                           3.579898,
                           3.941920,
                           3.486909,
                           3.058381,
                           3.055673,
                           2.512489,
                           2.553416,
                           2.190190))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value, label = round(value, 1))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(hjust=-.45, vjust=.4) +
  labs(y = "Vertrauen", x = "") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

The plot is simple: Initialize your data, set x and y values as well as the values for your label (in this case `values`), add a `geom_point` and `geom_text` layer and flip the coordinates. Don't forget to `reorder` your data to get the "from high to low" representation. Add the x-axis label and your desired theme --> done.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the plot with your help. Thanks for the help and the tip to include a example next time

Answer (score 1):

The plot you show looks like a combination of `geom_point` and perhaps `geom_errorbar` or `geom_linerange`e.g.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.0)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip()
```

There are multiple ways to achieve the plot you show. With a reproducible example, we can help be more specific.